# Discord.py prints message 7 times instead of once

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a code that matches the user's coins to a pattern and then tells the user the number of matches that they have. But for some reason at the end when I display the number of matches it displays it 7 times.

The code is:

```py
@client.command()
async def matches(ctx): 
  with open("Shibaku1.json") as f:
    coins_data = json.load(f)
    matches = 0 
    for coin1 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin1 == dcoin1:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin2 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin2 == dcoin2:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin3 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin3 == dcoin3:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin4 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin4 == dcoin4:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin5 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin5 == dcoin5:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin6 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin6 == dcoin6:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

      if matches > 0:
        await ctx.send(f'Shibaku1 has {matches} matches')
      else:
        matches = 0
```

The code to store user coins in `"Shibaku1.json"` is:

```py
@client.command()
async def Shibaku1(ctx, coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6, shibakunumber):

    with open('Shibaku1.json', 'r') as f:
      coins_data = json.load(f)
    coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)] = (coin1, coin2, coin3, coin4, coin5, coin6, shibakunumber)
    with open('Shibaku1.json', 'w') as f:
      json.dump(coins_data, f)
```

Comment: Indentation is your problem. Final `if` clause is executed inside `for coin6...` loop, so is executed every time. Unindent last 4 rows for one level. That's why style guide `pep8` recommends using 4 spaces per each indentation level.

Comment: Just add return in the if statement if coin match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with identation. Do this:

```
@client.command()
async def matches(ctx): 
  with open("Shibaku1.json") as f:
    coins_data = json.load(f)
    matches = 0 
    for coin1 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin1 == dcoin1:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin2 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin2 == dcoin2:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin3 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin3 == dcoin3:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin4 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin4 == dcoin4:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin5 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin5 == dcoin5:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    for coin6 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin6 == dcoin6:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

    if matches > 0:
        await ctx.send(f'Shibaku1 has {matches} matches')
    else:
        matches = 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Change those last lines:

```py
for coin6 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin6 == dcoin6:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches

      if matches > 0:
        await ctx.send(f'Shibaku1 has {matches} matches')
      else:
        matches = 0
```

in:

```py
for coin6 in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
      if coin6 == dcoin6:        
        matches = matches + 1
      else:
        matches = matches
if matches > 0:
      await ctx.send(f'Shibaku1 has {matches} matches')
else:
      matches = 0
```

Your indentation is wrong, so the if statement will loop in the for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

Much more understandable and conscious (but note that `dcoin1, ..., dcoin6` are not defined):

```py
@client.command()
async def matches(ctx): 
    with open("Shibaku1.json") as f:
        coins_data = json.load(f)
    
    matches = 0
    for coin in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]:
        for ref in [dcoin1, dcoin2, dcoin3, dcoin4, dcoin5, dcoin6]:
            if coin == ref:        
                matches += 1

    if matches > 0:
        await ctx.send(f'Shibaku1 has {matches} matches')
```

Or (better or worse - it depends) use the fact that `bool` is interpreted as integer in addition context.

```py
@client.command()
async def matches(ctx): 
    with open("Shibaku1.json") as f:
        coins_data = json.load(f)
    
    matches = sum(coin == ref
                  for coin in coins_data[str(ctx.author.id)]
                  for ref in [dcoin1, dcoin2, dcoin3, dcoin4, dcoin5, dcoin6])

    if matches > 0:
        await ctx.send(f'Shibaku1 has {matches} matches')
```

Also note that, for instance, if `coins` and `dcoins` are both unique sets, then you can write code even more readable using `set`

Comment: Thanks :D, I've set "dcoin" as a global variable as it is the main pattern to be compared with